# Does DispatchGroup wait forever?

Tags: swift, multithreading, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, dispatchgroup

I am wondering about the following scenario.

I have a `DispatchGroup` inside a function. Now I am entering the group on a background thread and calling `wait()`.

```swift
func test() {
   let group = DispatchGroup()
   
   DispatchQueue.global().async {
      group.enter()
      group.wait()
   }
}
```

My question is whether the group will wait forever or get deallocated after the main thread leaves the function?

I am not sure if there is any referencing or capturing. I would be very thankful for some explanation, this topic confuses me a bit.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will wait forever.

The `group` is captured, so it will not get released. And, obviously, you will end up lock that particular worker thread. As worker threads are quite limited, this is a bigger concern than the amount of memory consumed by the `DispatchGroup`.

If you want it to timeout, use [`wait(timeout:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup/1780590-wait).

Comment: Just a small addition to the otherwise great answer: for this exact reason, it's usually better to use `DispatchGroup.notify(queue:execute)`, which doesn't block the queue, but waits asynchronously.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much to both of you :)